# org-babel python output drawing and print text at the same time

Tags: org-mode

I like to use org-babel to write tiny python code and drawing with matplotlib. but I can only output drawing or text, I have to switch the org header from "file link" to "output" each time if I want to see print output.

How can I enable both then no need to swich header options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `#+CALL` macro. In this example, evaluate the second code block (*emacs-lisp*), it will first run the *R* block and then pass its value to the *emacs-lisp* block. I copied this from the manual, so you may want to read further there about it - chapter 14.

```
#+NAME: random
#+begin_src R :cache yes
  runif(1)
#+end_src

#+NAME: caller
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var x=random
  x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: caller
: 0.397210547933355
```